# Using PowerShell, is it possible to call IUpdateInstaller4.Commit without a type library or COM interop DLL?

Tags: c#, powershell, com, wuapi

This question is essentially a follow-up to a 6+ years old question here:
[IUpdateInstaller4::Commit not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513440/iupdateinstaller4commit-not-found)

As stated by Hans Passant in that answer, *at the time,* not only was the type library missing this interface entirely, but others (like IUpdateInstaller3) as well.

Fast forward to now, versions of Windows 10 20H2 and newer actually have a wuapi.dll that contains a complete type library within wuapi.dll, and the MSDN documentation has been updated.

Here is the link to theIUpdateInstaller4 interface (along with the rest of the previously missing interfaces):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nn-wuapi-iupdateinstaller4

That said, **on older versions of Windows 10, if you are installing a feature update, IUpdateInstaller4.Commit must be called in order for the feature update to properly install.** My observation is that if you fail to do this, you are likely to end up with a Windows installation that either rolls back or leaves your system in a nearly unusable state (ask me how I know).

I am looking for a way using native powershell to be able to call the Commit method on older versions of Windows 10, such as Windows 10 1909. The only success I have had so far was to create a COM interop DLL on a newer version of Windows 10 (such as 21H2) and bring that COM interop DLL back over to the 1909 machine and utilize it--**but I am looking for a way to do this without having to ship an entire DLL to a machine.** I suspect there is a way to do this with Add-Type and some C# code, which is my ideal solution so that the entire Windows Update process can be handled by the Powershell script I've authored.

There are many, many things I have tried that DO work on Win 10 20H2+, but do **NOT** work on Windows 10 1909. An acceptable answer is something that works on ALL versions of Windows 10.

I have tried various ways of declaring IUpdateInstaller4 (using decompiled definitions from the COM interop DLL I generated, and bringing the type in with Add-Type) without success. Each time I try something along those lines, like this:

```
[wuapi.IUpdateInstaller4].GetType().InvokeMember('Commit',[Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $UpdateInstaller, @(0))
```

...I get an exception such as:

```
Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "Object does not match target type."
At line:85 char:2
 +     [wuapi.IUpdateInstaller4].GetType().InvokeMember('Commit',[Reflec …
 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TargetException
```

I'm fairly certain someone who is familiar with the inner workings of COM (such as Hans Passant) would probably have a quick solution.

---

Additional information/code based on questions in the comments. Here is a snippet of the script that installs the updates (based on creating an $UpdateSearchString that is constructed based on several script parameters)

```
$Searcher = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Searcher
$Searcher.ServiceID = $UpdateServiceID
$Results = $Searcher.Search($UpdatesSearchString)
$Results.Updates | % {if($_.EulaAccepted -eq $false){$_.AcceptEula()}}
$UpdateList = $Results.Updates
$Updates = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$UpdateList | % {$null = $Updates.Add($_)}
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$UpdateInstaller = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
while($UpdateInstaller.IsBusy) {Start-Sleep 5}
$UpdateInstaller.Updates = $Updates
$InstallResult = $UpdateInstaller.Install()
```

On Windows 10, you should be able to do this:

```
$CommitResult = $UpdateInstaller.Commit(0)
```

...but that does not work unless you are on a version of Windows 10 that has the updated type library in the wuapi COM dll.

The following code works on a machine with an updated wuapi.dll, but not older versions (and fails with the exception posted above):

```
$Source = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace wuapi
{
  [TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FHidden | TypeLibTypeFlags.FDual | TypeLibTypeFlags.FNonExtensible | TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
  [Guid("EF8208EA-2304-492D-9109-23813B0958E1")]
  [ComImport]
  public interface IUpdateInstaller4 : IUnknown
  {
    [DispId(1610874882)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    int Commit([In] uint dwFlags);
  }
  [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    public interface IUnknown
    {
    }
  public static class UpdateCommitter
  {
    public static int Commit(IUnknown comObject, uint dwFlags)
    {
        var updateInstaller = comObject as IUpdateInstaller4;
        return updateInstaller.Commit(dwFlags);
    }
  }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source
$CommitResult=[wuapi.IUpdateInstaller4].InvokeMember('Commit',[Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null,  $UpdateInstaller, @(0))
```

Comment: You can always add C# to a Powershell script (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208197/how-can-i-use-add-type-to-add-c-sharp-code-with-system-windows-forms-namespace) and with C# and a scriptable API you can use the `dynamic` keyword coolness which should work on this WUAPI. Do you have an example of a code you want to run (in C# or C++, VB, etc.)?

Comment: I have added more info about what I've tried--specifically an example that I know is "correct" because it works on new versions of Windows 10, but still does not work on older versions with the incomplete type library.

Comment: I can't test by myself, but can you test this https://gist.github.com/smourier/88731b773e0d665743ff723bf8bd80e8

Comment: See if following remarks helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdatedownloader-download#remarks

Comment: @SimonMourier :

Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "Object does not match target type."
At line:55 char:2
+     [wuapi.IUpdateInstaller4].GetType().InvokeMember('Commit',[Reflec …
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TargetException

Comment: @SimonMourier I made a change to call the static method in the UpdateCommitter and that appeared to call Commit without an exception. I need to test further, but this might be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, Simon Mourier put me on the right track to being able to call IUpdateInstaller4.Commit.

I'm not sure why even with this interface definition you cannot call Commit with:

```
$CommitResult=[wuapi.IUpdateInstaller4].InvokeMember('Commit',[Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null,  $UpdateInstaller, @(0))
```

..but it *can* be called indirectly via a static class/static method.

Here is an example that I have successfully tested and used the past couple of days on both older versions of Windows 10 as well as Server 2016, 2019, 2022, and Windows 11.

```
$Source = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace wuapi
{
    [ComImport, Guid("ef8208ea-2304-492d-9109-23813b0958e1"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IUpdateInstaller4
    {
        void _VtblGap0_29(); // skip 4 (IDispatch) + 25 IUpdateInstaller4 methods
        [PreserveSig]
        int Commit(uint dwFlags);
    }
    public static class UpdateCommitter
    {
        public static int Commit(object comObject, uint dwFlags)
        {
            var updateInstaller = (IUpdateInstaller4)comObject;
            return updateInstaller.Commit(dwFlags);
        }
    }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source
[int]$CommitResult = [wuapi.UpdateCommitter]::Commit($UpdateInstaller,0)
```